# Email Script Firing Duplicate

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have an email script I've been working on that part works but there is an issue with duplicating emails.  The email does fire correctly but the next time the script runs it fires a duplicate when it shouldn't?

Here is my data structure in the sheet.

Date:  From Email:  Business Email:  Message:   Business Name:  Business ID:  From ID:  Email Status:

Here is my code.

```
var EMAIL_SENT = 'EMAIL_SENT';
function sendEmails2() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Contact Form Submissions");
    sheet.activate()
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var startRow = 2; // First row of data to process
    var numRows = 1; // Number of rows to process
    var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 8);
    // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
    var data = dataRange.getValues();
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
        var row = data[i];
        var emailSent = row[8];
        Logger.log(data);
        if (emailSent !== EMAIL_SENT) { // Prevents sending duplicates
            var subject = 'RE: QTown user contact form submission for ' + row[4];
            var emailAddress = row[2];
            var message = 'Greetings!\n\nOn ' + row[0] + ', ' + row[1] + ' submitted a contact form from your profile on QTown.\n\nThe Message:\n' + row[3] + '\n\nPlease respond to the users questions as soon as possible.\n\nThank you!\nQT';
            MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
            sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 8).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);
            // Make sure the cell is updated right away in case the script is interrupted
            SpreadsheetApp.flush();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Issue:

The issue is that you are storing `EMAIL_SENT` in column `8` which is column `H`:

```
sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 8).setValue(EMAIL_SENT)
```

but then in the if condition you are checking for column `9` which is column `I` because array indexes in JavaScript start from `0`.

```
var emailSent = row[8]
```

### Solution:

Store `EMAIL_SENT` in column `H`:

**Replace:**

```
var emailSent = row[8]
```

**with:**

```
var emailSent = row[7]
```

---

Store `EMAIL_SENT` in column `I`:

**Replace**:

```
sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 8).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);
```

**with:**

```
sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 9).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);
```